# Linux box, counting files each subfolder in directory

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin

I already have this line for Linux box.

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec ls -l {} \;
```

It's getting all the TXT files in directory. But what I can't do and what I want to do is, to read all the .txt files on subfolder in one directory.

For example : ParentTxtFolder --> ChildTxtFolder --> Txtfolder1, Txtfolder2, Txtfolder3. Per one Txtfolder it contains .txt files.

So what I want is, to scan Txtfolder1 and count .txtfiles.

If this output is possible, Expected output :

```
Txtfolder1 - 14
Txtfolder2 - 10
Txtfolder3 - 18
```

I'm really stuck on this one. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do it is like this:

```
for d in `find . -type d` ; do echo -n "$d: " ; find "$d" -type f -depth 1 -name \*.txt | wc -l ; done
```

or less succinctly:

```
for d in `find . -type d`   # for each directory
  do
    echo -n "$d: "          # print directory name
    find "$d" -type f -depth 1 -name \*.txt | wc -l
  done                      # followed by count of .txt files in directory
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure what the question is. But `for x in $(command with not always standard output)` is an extremely error prone syntax. You want `find . -type d -print0 | while IFS= -r -d $'\0' d; do ... ; done` to take care of all weird file/directory names.

Comment: Thanks for this one. This one what am I looking for. But the problem here is the depth level. I don't need to specify a depth level. But it's working. Thanks dude.

Comment: @BroSlow: thanks for the suggestion - you're probably right - I'm a bit of an amateur when it comes to bash scripting. I'm assuming the OP is happy with a "quick and dirty" solution, but I'm sure it can be made more robust in regard to weird directory/file names etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.txt' | awk '$NF=""; {a[$0]++} END{for( i in a) print i, a[i]}' FS=/
.  2
. foo  1
. foo bar  2
```

In this example, there are 2 files in ., 1 in foo, and 2 and in foo/bar.  This output is not *exactly* what you want, but it's not clear that the differences are relevant.